# Closed-loop systems - discrepancy between Simulink and Arduino

Tags: arduino, control-system, pid-controller, matlab, simulink

I am trying to figure out how to reproduce closed-loop systems in Arduino that were designed initially designed in Simulink.

Take the following closed-loop system with unity feedback and gain:

[image]

Where Gp(z) is a discrete transfer function, taking the form of:

\$Gp(z) = \frac{0.1288z - 0.06234}{z^2 - 0.7813z + 0.1817}\$

The closed-loop system was replicated in Arduino with the following code:

```
int iteration(0);
double y(0), e(0);
double Gp_y_0(0), Gp_y_1(0), Gp_y_2(0), Gp_x_0(0), Gp_x_1(0), Gp_x_2(0);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

double Gp_z (double Gp_x_0) {
  Gp_y_0 = (0.128767938742003 * Gp_x_1) + (-0.062336933973903 * Gp_x_2) - (-0.781272292546052 * Gp_y_1) - (0.181746970098960 * Gp_y_2);
  Gp_x_2 = Gp_x_1;
  Gp_x_1 = Gp_x_0;
  Gp_y_2 = Gp_y_1;
  Gp_y_1 = Gp_y_0;
  return Gp_y_0;
}

void loop() {
  delay(500);
  e = 20.0 - y;
  y = Gp_z(e);
  Serial.print(iteration); Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(e, 9); Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(y, 9);
  Serial.println();
  iteration++;
}
```

The plant, Gp, is implemented correctly in Arduino. I tested its open-loop response was tested with a step input - the values acquired matched MATLAB with 12 digits of precision.

However, when I close the loop, I notice that after the first iteration the output is different than the output in Simulink. Arduino shows more oscillations in the step response than shown in Simulink. I am convinced that the reasoning for this is order of operations. *My goal is to match the output of Arduino with the simulations I am getting from Simulink - I just can't seem to match them.*

Here is the first 10 samples (Interation#, Error, Output):

### Arduino

```
0   20.000000000    0.000000000
1   20.000000000    2.575358775
2   17.424641225    3.340676550
3   16.659323450    3.138910827
4   16.861089173    2.904174249
5   17.095825751    2.831139893
6   17.168860107    2.834391925
7   17.165608075    2.844978145
8   17.155021855    2.847686323
9   17.152313677    2.846717691
```

### Simulink

```
0  20.000000000000000                   0
1  17.424641225159935   2.575358774840067
2  16.990947091447396   3.009052908552605
3  17.015483465319324   2.984516534680677
4  17.083280988271159   2.916719011728840
5  17.124589277883938   2.875410722116062
6  17.143447412039610   2.856552587960392
7  17.150819802325874   2.849180197674125
8  17.153378468604828   2.846621531395171
9  17.154167672101366   2.845832327898634
```

By looking into the numbers, it may not seem like a big difference but when designing a controller, its VERY significant, almost making Simulink design tools useless when implementing into Arduino.

Thank you,

**EDIT:** Clarification for Gp_z() function in Arduino. To implement a discrete transfer function, such as Gp(z) into Arduino. I performed an inverse Z-transform on Gp(z):

1. Multiply Gp(z) by \$\frac{z^{-2}}{z^{-2}}\$:

\$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{0.1288z^{-1} - 0.06234z^{-2}}{1 - 0.7813z^{-1} + 0.1817z^{-2}}\$

2. Isolate Y(z):

\$Y(z) = X(z)0.1288z^{-1} - X(z)0.06234z^{-2} + Y(z)0.7813z^{-1} - Y(z)0.1817z^{-2}\$

3. Inverse Z-transform:

\$y[n] = 0.1288x[n-1] - 0.06234x[n-2] + 0.7813y[n-1] - 0.1817y[n-2]\$

This formula was implemented in Gp_z() function.

**UPDATE:** By switching the execution order of *e* and *y* in Arduino:

```
void loop() {
  delay(500);
  y = Gp_z(e);
  e = 20.0 - y;
  Serial.print(iteration); Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(e, 9); Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(y, 9); Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.println();
  iteration++;
}
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
0   20.000000000    0.000000000 
1   20.000000000    0.000000000 
2   17.424641225    2.575358775 
3   16.659323450    3.340676550 
4   16.861089173    3.138910827 
5   17.095825751    2.904174249 
6   17.168860107    2.831139893 
7   17.165608075    2.834391925 
8   17.155021855    2.844978145 
9   17.152313677    2.847686323
```

There is an extra iteration of initial conditions and the numbers look better but still with significant overshoot in comparison to Simulink. I don't believe this to be the solution to the problem.

Comment: How can the error still be 20.000000000 in the 2nd line of the arduino result? It looks like you are "one step" out in part of your implementation thus gradually throwing the rest of the numbers out.

Comment: Arduino step 1 is  wrong : the Error associated with step 1 (17.42) is presented in step 2 (alongside Step 2's output not Step 1's) and it all goes downhill after that.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, this is was I was trying to say in the original question. However, I think Arduino is correct here, because if the output is 0.000 in Step 0 than the error should remain 20.00 in Step 1. It makes sense to me - I hope I am wrong though.

Comment: @DannyGelman column 3 plus column 2 should equal the step input of 20. Clearly and unambiguously this doesn't happen in step 2 for the Arduino.

Comment: @Andyaka That makes a lot of sense. So what am I doing wrong in my Arduino code? I am positive that I implemented Gp(z) properly.

Comment: I'm sure someone will figure that out - I'm not the man for coding problems but I can read an error in a table when I see one. Also, it would help if you put the full formula into the question rather than assume folk will work this out to see if your code is correct.

Comment: @Andyaka, What full formula did I omit? I will add any more information thats needed.

Comment: Gp(z) is the large rectangle and you have a numerator and denominator that defines Gp(z). That is the only formula you have stated yet, the full system has another layer of feedback and a summing junction - you have not stated what the full formula is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63623/discussion-between-danny-gelman-and-andy-aka).

Comment: In other words I can't match this: Gp_y_0 = (0.128767938742003 * Gp_x_1) + (-0.062336933973903 * Gp_x_2) - (-0.781272292546052 * Gp_y_1) - (0.181746970098960 * Gp_y_2) with anything.

Comment: when you simulated in simulink, did you also do fixed-step at 500ms? Simulink will usually use variable timestep by default YET you are implementing in a fixed-step/digital domain. 500ms is HUGE!  there is also the executution time of the arduino.  Basically retune the module to match your physical constrains

Comment: @JonRB Illustrated in the question is a closed-loop system with unity gain and unity feedback - essentially a P-controller with P=1. P controllers are not depending on time. So it shouldn't matter if the sampling time is 1 ms vs 1 hr, the math will still be the same. Of course, this is different with PID controllers, and I understand that - but for this question, sampling time is irrelevant.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DannyGelman 1st order systems don't overshoot. that TF isn't 1st order

Comment: [Here is the open-loop step response of Gp(z).](https://gyazo.com/5ad2b4d3b7ae1322b9e46c28de1e776a) My question is concerning the execution order and how to properly perform the correct maths to get the proper closed-loop response in Arduino.

Comment: Are you using an Arduino UNO or another Arduino board based on ATmega MCUs? If yes, are you aware that the `double` data type is exactly the same as `float`, i.e. it is implemented as an IEEE single precision floating point? This means 5-6 (IIRC) decimal digits of precision, not 12, as you assume. I didn't examine your code, but numerical error can accumulate quite fast in an iterative algorithm if you don't have enough precision in your floating point numbers.

Comment: I am using an Arduino Due. I tested open-loop step responses of Gp up to 9 digits (as shown) and they were identical to output in Simulink. I am certain it the precision wouldn't escalade so quickly after the 1st iteration - I am more convinced that this is an order of operations problem.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I believe Andy is correct. The error in Step 1 (Arduino) should NOT be 20.000. It should be 17.42 as shown in Step 1 for Simulink. The problem is that the output for Step 0 is 0.000, which makes the error in Step 1 20.000. To me that makes sense, but Simulink doesn't show that.

Comment: If you are using an Arduino DUE, then I retract my objection, since your doubles are indeed 64bits wide.